# will installing jdk16 install Java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java

novice to these stuffs. I want to start working on Java EE. I have jdk1.6 installed. Will I have the features of Java EE? (mind: I am working on a web app, and I have like apache tomcat, ant..)

Answer (score 0):

JDK is only for standard java application not enterprise applications. However, if you have a web container such as `Tomcat` you will not need to install anything further and you can start develop dynamic web applications (e.g. `Servlet` and `JSP`)

If you want to develop `EJB` you will need application server such as `JBOSS`

Answer (score 0):

Java EE is a collection of standards, like EJB, JPA, JSF and others. It's bit counterintuitive, but you never get to install Java EE as a package called "javaEE.jar" or such.

In order to develop Java EE applications, you only need them to know the according APIs, without having to provide the implementations with your application. The implementations are provided by multiple Java EE compliant application servers.

The default implementation of Java EE is the [Glassfish AS](http://glassfish.java.net/). There are others like [JBoss AS](http://www.jboss.org/) and [Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) . Here is a  [complete list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html).

Starting with Java EE 6, the specification defines a smaller subset of standards, especially for web application development, known as the [Java EE Web Profile](http://jaxenter.com/introducing-the-java-ee-web-profile-36201.html). If you want to develop web applications exclusively, it's worth a look.